# Controls on inherited form are locked, can it be undone?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-inheritance

**Setup:**

I have created a `Form` that I wish to have serve as the base from which I will inherit other forms.  This base form serves as a "template" of sorts, but it also provides a good deal of functionality related to the structure, as well as the interrelation of all of the controls provided.

A primer for the images that follow...  The top info-colored bar is a custom control inherited from `ToolStrip`.  The bottom strip is another custom, again inherited from `ToolStrip`.  The left white block is a `TreeView` and the right block is a `TabControl` (having deleted all `TabPages` from it...I intend for these to be added in the inherited forms).

**Image of base form in designer:**

[image]

**Image of inherited form in designer:**

[image]

Clearly, the only difference is that when I open the inherited form, I get a little box icon superimposed over each control, and when I click them, I get the padlock telling me I cannot edit.

**The problems:**

All controls on the inherited form are locked.  I have researched the issue of [visual inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z3efhd2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and as far as I can tell, I'm not using any controls that expressly do not support it, as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046328/how-to-access-inherited-controls-in-the-winforms-designer) suggests there are.  In [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392337/control-seems-to-be-locked), Hans suggests changing the modifier on those controls, which I have done.  In fact, I tried both `Public` and `Protected`, all to no good result.

I am stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a technical restriction in the designer, it is specific to the SplitContainer control you are using.  And some other ones.  The trouble-maker is the ISupportInitialize interface.

Controls use this interface when they can't afford the properties of the control to be assigned in an arbitrary order.  The designer helps when it sees that the control implements this interface, it calls the BeginInit() method when it starts assigning properties, EndInit() when it is done.  The control uses these methods to delay the side-effect of property assignments, the EndInit() method makes them effective.  Important for SplitContainer, the minimum sizes of the panels also affect the splitter position.

Perhaps you can see the rub, the InitializeComponent() method in the base form class has already called ISupportInitialize.EndInit().  So modifying properties again in the derived form class is unlikely to turn out well.  The designer protects the control from this by locking it.

Very inconvenient, there is no simple workaround.  If modifying the SplitContainer in the derived form class is a hard requirement then you'll have to give up on inheriting it or write the code by hand in the derived class constructor.

Comment: That underlying control is actually a `TableLayoutPanel`.  I checked its lineage, and I don't see `ISupportInitialize` there.  Does what you're describing still apply?

Comment: Sigh.  No, it doesn't.  It is a specific designer restriction for TLP, I don't know the exact issue.

Comment: Well here's the definitive statement:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171689(v=vs.90).aspx.  Doesn't say why, unfortunately.  Thanks for the input, Hans.