# Tabledlayoutpanel has locked in descending controls (WinForms C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building an library of Winforms controls, and one is a responsive usercontrol. To it, i use a Windows.Forms TableLayoutPainel on this usercontrol.

My problem: When i create child controls of this user control, the design in tabledlayoutpanel's work area are locked...

- Property "modifiers" already set as "Protected".
- I try put more panels about tabledpanel but it no fixed the problem.

Please visit this link to see pictures: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28496/tabledlayoutpanel-bloqueado-em-controles-herdados-winforms-c

Comment: Known issue with `TableLayoutPanel`, you will not make this work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controls on inherited form are locked, can it be undone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181926/controls-on-inherited-form-are-locked-can-it-be-undone)