# Unable to Move Control on Windows Form Designer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a user control called ucCompPriceSummary on my form in VB.NET 2010. For some reason I am unable to relocate this control to the bottom of my form.

It can't be dragged, moved with arrow keys, or resized.

None of the controls on the form, nor the form itself is locked.

Any ideas?

Note: Multiple people worked on this program and I am assigned to it now. So it may have been some set property or something.

Comment: I had the same issue once:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181926/controls-on-inherited-form-are-locked-can-it-be-undone

Comment: There is a property called `Locked` in system.windows.forms.control. change it from `true` to `false`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Perfect, thanks for clearing that up!