# Adding Controls to inherited UserControl in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, user-controls

I created a new UserControl that inherits my `BaseUserControl`. The `BaseUserControl` has a FlowLayoutPanel, where i would like to place some new controls in Design Mode. The properties are greyed out in the inherited UserControl, altough I set the modifier of the FlowLayoutPanel to Public:

```
'BaseUserControl.Designer.vb:
Friend WithEvents pnlNavbar As Panel
Friend WithEvents btnSave As Button
Public WithEvents flpContent As FlowLayoutPanel
```

How do i make the FlowLayoutPanel accessible in the inherited UserControl?

Comment: Visual inheritante in .NET is a pain, I think you will not be able to access the parent's panel from VS designer so.

Comment: OK after searching for "visual inheritance flowlayoutpanel" I figured out, not to use FlowLayoutPanel in this case and rather switch to the normal panel. See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1735092/5052167](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1735092/5052167)