# DataGridView properties are disable in child form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a parent form (Form1) and a child form (Form2) that inherits from the former. They have one button and one datagridview control.

[image]

When i start to work on the child form (Form2), in design mode, my button properties are enabled but datagridview all  properties are disabled, eventhough I set their modifiers to public.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I change these properties in the child form for DataGridView?

Comment: Can you post the code for the base form and how it's used?  Specifically I want to see the constructors and class definitions for both.  This sounds like a [Visual Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046328/how-to-access-inherited-controls-in-the-winforms-designer) problem.

Comment: You need a custom control derived from DataGridView, decorate the class with a Designer attribute (as `[Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]`, for example, unless you have your own designers, but it's the same), then set its `Modifier = Public` in the base Form. If your derived Form is opened, close it. Rebuild the Solution. Reopen the derived Form. Watch out because the DGV's constructor in the base class, IIRC, may not be called at all (but it will be in the derived Form). Anyway, the DGV in the derived Form should be editable now

Comment: Also, now that I think about it, the Smart Tags (what causes the main problem, IIRC), won't probably be there in the derived Form. It may not be a big issue but...

Comment: @Jimi, that solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: [C# Winforms visual inheritance problem with DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998314/c-sharp-winforms-visual-inheritance-problem-with-datagridview)